# Windows 7 & Age of Empires II: works but not quite?

Tags: windows-7, technical-issues, age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Age of Empires II Scrolling Bug](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20826/the-age-of-empires-ii-scrolling-bug)

I'm trying to install Age of Empires II on Windows 7.

The graphics are so so, but when I enter a tutorial, the map keeps panning continuously, to the upper left of the screen especially.  It doesn't seem to be the mouse, I have lifted it off of the pad, and it still pans automatically...

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: do you have a game pad, flight stick or other peripheral attached?

Comment: @Xantec: nope....

Comment: I have just upgraded to Windows 7 and am gonna try AoE-II this weekend. I'll let you know of my experience when I do that.

Comment: that would be awesome @6packkid

Comment: Worked fine for me. I have even played multi-player at Voobly and it worked fine.

Comment: really?! I can install it, and everything @6packkid, but when I go to the game map, and start to play (in the tutorials, at least), the map pans continously, etc as I mentioned above....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think its Windows 7 actually.  The scrolling glitch is something that happened back in the XP days as well.

Do you have a Zune?  A lot of people who have experienced the scrolling glitch have had Zunes, and after uninstalling the Zune drivers and software the problem has been fixed.

Another fix that used to work for people was powering off the computer, unplugging all peripherals, then once you get to the desktop/login screen, plug them all back in.  You might try that as well.

Comment: *jaw drops* This may have something to do with Zune? interesting!  I have several Zunes and use them with my machine frequently... +1 for the answer, will have to try some of these things!

Comment: Yeah, its one of the weirder problems I've seen.  The only reason I know about it is that I had a friend who had the same issue a few years ago.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried modifying the shortcut to use compatibility modes for previous windows versions?

Comment: I've tried running it in compatibility mode for Windows XP SP3...but no luck

Answer (score 4):

I have found a fix for this:

I did not have to uninstall zune to fix it either.

I believe that it is one of the Zune processes that is causing the scrolling problem. If you don't start zune(and kill all processes) Age of Empires II  will work.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any documented fix(es) anywhere for installing Age of Empires II on Windows 7...so will stick with Windows XP for that!

Answer (score 2):

That scrolling bug should be fixed by the community-made (non-official) AOE II: The Conquerors patch, **[UserPatch](https://userpatch.aiscripters.net/)** | https://userpatch.aiscripters.net/ :

> This is a feature and bug-fix update for Age of Empires II: The Conquerors Expansion. Its primary focus is to correct several long existing issues with the AI system and related game elements.

Among many other [fixes and improvements to AOE II: The Conquerors](https://userpatch.aiscripters.net/), one if its core features is:

> Uncontrollable game view scrolling bug has been fixed

Note that [the UserPatch installer must be run with admin privileges in order for it to be able to install all of its fixes](https://twitter.com/xOmicron/status/145792429403017216).